# Naming: What to call the "regular" page request environment(compared to shell or JSON request)?

Tags: php, naming

I'm working on an user interaction class that uses a set of driver classes to handle user interaction in different "environments":

- **Shell** to handle interaction inside shell
- **JSON** to handle interaction through Ajax/JSON messages
- **foo** to handle interaction between regular page loads

What name should I use in place of **foo** ?

Edit:

I ask this because I don't know if an accurate term for **foo** exists at all and googling for something you don't even know exists will rarely have any success :)

The classes are currently named like `InteractiveShellHandler` and `InteractiveJSONHandler`. *Interactive* is the name of the main library.

Ideally, I'd like to follow the same naming convention that is used widely in the project but if a better one comes up that allows a sane name for **foo** and others, I can change it for this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would name the command line interface (shell) interface **CLI**, and the web interface **HTTP**. The **AJAX** interface would extend **HTTP**

- Request\Cli
- Request\Http
- Request\Http\Ajax

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Although I too considered **HTTP**, I need to follow some naming conventions and **HTTP** and **HTTP/Ajax** don't fit that well. I was hoping that a specific term for this existed that I'd missed due to my limited vocabulary. If nothing else comes up, I will probably use HTTP and mark your answer accepted.